# UITableViewCell textLabel attributedText iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, nsattributedstring

I am trying to set an attributedtext as the value for "textlabel" in a Basic UITableViewCell. 
However, the cell is shown as blank! Here is teh code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSDictionary *docattr = [NSDictionary new];
NSError *myerror = [NSError new];
NSString *htmlString = [[[dm latestUpdates] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"display_data"];
NSMutableAttributedString *updateText = 
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                        options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, 
                                                  NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} 
                             documentAttributes:&docattr 
                                          error:&myerror];

[cell.textLabel setAttributedText:updateText];
//   cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = updateText;
NSLog(@"cell text %@", cell.textLabel.text);
//   cell.textLabel.text = htmlString;
return cell;
```

The above code translates my html to a valid attributed string. but nothing is shown. the html in question is

```
<div class='title'><a href='mc://guru_txn/171'>Wilbur Ross bought EXCO Resources, Inc.</a></div><div class='description'>Wilbur Ross bought 19,599,973 shares of EXCO Resources, Inc. (<a href='mc://quotes/XCO'>XCO</a>) @ $5.00 per share on 2014-01-17.</div>
```

I donot know how to specify the values i want various "class"es. However, the html fragment above is parsed into a valid attributed string.

Comment: try [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:htmlString]

Comment: Doesn't help, the html is not parsed.

Comment: Instead of using UILabel, use UIWebView with interaction=NO and scrollEnabled=NO.

Comment: I am seeing this as well. Maybe an iOS bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, there seems to be something wrong with your html string.

I tried setting htmlString to @"`<div>Test</div>`" and it worked. However, when I wrapped "test" in  tag, it wouldn't be visible anymore.

Hope this will help you to solve it.

P.S.: Also, try not to allocate objects in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method. It can really slow down your scrolling.

Comment: well, i tried setting it to some basic html @"<b>test</b>". That doesn't work either. Also, while I allocate cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I am using dynamic prototypes, and this is the recommended code from apple. I tried <p></p> as well. same result. Empty tableview cells.

Comment: I tried modifying the UITableViewCell prototype to say that the textLabel is attributed, but that doesn't help either

Comment: @"<b>test</b>" worked for me as well as @"<div>test</div>" or @"<p>test</p>" but as soon as I add a link tag like @"<a href='...'>test</a>" it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I noticed that removing href property from <a> solves it, but a looses its point then